# When I change the route, the new page appears from below

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In App.js I already have the routes defined

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  HashRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="container"></div>
      </div>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route
          path="/ConsultaEstadoTramite"
          element={<ConsultaEstadoTramite />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
};
```

I present this code example of a button, which directs me to another page:

```html
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./ConsultaTramite.scss";

export default function ConsultaTramite() {
  return (
    <div className="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
      <div className="tarjeta-acciones mb-4">
        <div className="head-acciones titulo-acciones">
          <Link to="/ConsultaEstadoTramite" className="irTramite">
            <h6 className="titulo-card">
              Consulta el Estado de tu Solicitud
            </h6>
          </Link>          
        </div>
        <div className="body-acciones">
          <p className="texto-card">
            Consulta el estado de tu Trámite de Homologación de Equipos Terminales Móviles ante la Comisión de Regulación de Comunicaciones.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But when it transports me to this page, it shows the content from the footer, and I have to move to the top.

What should I include in the code so that it is always displayed from the top.

consultation

This is happening to me with several route change links.

Answer (score 0):

React router renders the route components within the `<Routes></Routes>` tag.
You should place them on the section of the page you want the route to be displayed.

Imports: `import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';`

```
<main>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/ConsultaEstadoTramite" element={<ContentOfPath />} />
    <Route path="someOtherPath" element={<OtherContent />} />
  </Routes>
</main>
```

In the example above the routes will be displayed inside the `main` tag.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your contribution, but update the question, since the routes are already established in the App.js file.

When I use another component, which goes to the other page, it happens to me the problem that it starts to show the content from below.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem will be fixed implementing a scroll to top solution, as described in the React router documentation about Scroll restoration:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration